# How to fix drivers including LAN (Internet) after --purge remove *-desktop?

Tags: drivers, internet, ethernet

I just upgraded my Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04.
It was working good, until I switch Ubuntu-desktop to xubuntu-desktop. I tried xubuntu, and decided to move back to Ubuntu. So I just purged xubuntu-desktop.

After that I came with broken grub, broken Ubuntu etc etc.
I have fixed other things but still not able to repair my ethernet.

Following detail may helpful:

```
sudo lshw -C network

  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 0c
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:xxxx(size=256) memory:f7cxxxxx-f7c00fff memory:fxxxxxxx-f0003fff


cat /etc/network/interfaces

# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback


cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml

# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

Note: I don't have internet working so apt-get install won't work. Untill package is in apt cache.

Comment: Desktop or Server installation? Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C network` and `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: As you note, placing that output into comments is a nightmare to read. Please delete the comment, and edit it into your original question, using copy/paste, as I had asked. Then I'll take a look. Let me know when you've got it done.

Comment: @heynnema Updated questions. please have a look on it.

Comment: What happens when you do `sudo modprobe r8169`? Does the ethernet come back, or does it error out?

Comment: @heynnema `modprobe: FATAL: Module r8169 not found in directory /lib/modules/5.4.0-26-generic`

Comment: That's what I thought. Please see my answer. If it's helpful, please remember to accept it by clicking the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Status please...

Comment: @heynnema I found one solution and posted below, also i improved my question title. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@heynnema said it right, purging *-desktop will destroy drivers too.

But since network driver is also dead, `apt-get update` will not work.

In that case, installing all possible required packages which are saved and stored in apt cache resolved almost all issues. It may increase trash also, but this is alternate to reinstall os without harming data on non-partitions directories. Apt keeps their packages at `/var/cache/apt/archieve/`.

`dpkg -i <package_name>`, here all packages i wanted to install so in that case `dpkg -i *` works well.

Comment: dpkg doesn't do dependency checking like apt or apt-get, but in your case it's probably ok. Do/did you have a working wireless connection, as I suggested in my answer? If so, the r8168 driver would have been a good fix. Is your ethernet working now?

Comment: I didn't had any of networking connection working, installing all deb packages streamlined my system including networking also. As soon as i got everything back, i just hit `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` just to keep system more stable.

Comment: Good job! Thanks for the update!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, uninstalling `*-desktop` packages can destroy working systems. If you've been able to manually fix the bulk of the damage, congrats, however, you may ultimately need to reinstall Ubuntu.

Can you connect to the Internet using a wireless connection?

Your ethernet is failing because the r8169 kernel driver is missing from /lib/modules/5.4.0-26-generic.

Fastest/best way to solve it...

In the `terminal`...

`sudo apt-get update` # update the databases

`sudo apt-get install dkms r8168-dkms` # install a different driver

`reboot` # reboot the computer

Verify proper ethernet operation.

If ethernet still doesn't work properly, reinstall Ubuntu.